# Load Dynamic Control in Asp.net (Asp Page Lifecyle)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function to load a user control, it looks like this:

```
private void AddPopupControlToPage()
    {
        WidgetConfiguration popupControl = new WidgetConfiguration();
        popupControl = (WidgetConfiguration)LoadControl("~/Docking/Widgets/WidgetConfiguration.ascx");
        popupControl.ID = "PopupControlInput1";
        g_PopupControlId = popupControl.ClientID;
        popupControl.Attributes.Add("width", "150px");
        Form.Controls.Add(popupControl);
    }
```

I have drop down that allows me to change the page layout based on what template is selected. I should be able to press call the popup control from any template(page). Based on what I've read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx I should be able to load my control in the Page_PreInit event, however the form is not loaded at that point and I get a null reference error. Any ideas on how/where I should load my popup control and keep it available to any selected page?

Comment: is the control suppose to be populated before the main page content..? also look at a placeholder

Comment: Have you tried the `Page_Load` event as well?

Comment: The popup control is really separate from all the other controls, so it should be loaded before the main page content.

Comment: I get this error: Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

Comment: I get the error above when I load the control from the Page_Load event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should load a control always overriding the CreateChildControls method

soomething like

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        //now load your control here
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of how to do that Leonardo?

Comment: DJ, what is the reason for the change you suggest?